# What does "I'm calling" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> “Yeh could’ve died!” sobbed Hagrid. “An’ don’ say the name!”
>   “VOLDEMORT!” Harry bellowed, and Hagrid was so shocked, he stopped
>   crying. “I’ve met him and **I’m calling** him by his name. Please
>   cheer up, Hagrid, we saved the Stone, it’s gone, he can’t use it. Have
>   a Chocolate Frog, I’ve got loads…” 
>  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

```
“Do not use I’ll [instead of “I am doing”] for something you decided before.” 
(Essential Grammar in Use).
```

Consulting this, ‘I’m calling’ implies he’s already decided he would call You-Kow-Who by his name. Am I right?

Comment: While "I'm calling" does express Harry's intention of using Voldemort's name in the future, in this case it also expresses the fact that he is **right now** using Voldemort's name, as he just did at the beginning of the utterance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here ‘I’m calling’ implies that Harry has already decided on calling You-Kow-Who by his name, and he's not going to listen to anything that Hagrid has to say on this matter.

Comment: I don't know the technical language / grammar term for it, but I think the "am" is a verb (to be) that is both present and persisting into the future.